# Problema no meu código Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Pessoal esse é o meu código em `PHP`

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM noty");
while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $notificacao = $linha["notificacao"];

echo"<div class='adm_edit'>".$notificacao."
   <input type='text' class='input_edit' value='".$notificacao."'/>
</div>";
}
```

Como vocês podem ver estou pegando as informações do banco e mostrando. Até ai tudo certo, mas o problema vem no `JQuery`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".adm_edit").on("click", function() {
    $(this).children(".input_edit").show();
    $("#exit_edit").show();
});

$("#exit_edit").click(function() {
    $(".adm_edit").text($(".input_edit").val());
    $(".input_edit").hide();
    $("#exit_edit").hide();
});
});
```

Cada conteúdo que é gerado pelo banco como vocês podem ver tem uma `Input` invisível que é mostrada quando o usuário clica no conteúdo. O problema vem depois disso que é quando eu gostaria que quando a `Input`quando fosse fechada o conteúdo digitado ali passasse a ser da `Div` que foi clicada.

Comment: aonde está esse "#exit_edit" no arquivo php? está oculto mesmo?

Comment: **"como vocês podem ver tem uma Input invisível"**, desculpa. Mas não entendi essa frase, entrei num paradoxo.

Comment: Ia tentar ajudar, mas também achei confuso. Talvez alguém possa entender e ajudar, mas de repente é melhor tentar esclarecer melhor. Como não tenho uma noção visual dos elementos ficou meio difícil pra mim entender o que você chama de fechar input e também que div seria essa que teria um conteúdo a ser colocado no input.

Comment: @DiegodeSouzaSilva eu acabei não colocando o código do "exit.php" mas é uma div com "display:none" que serve para esconder a input quando clicada. Caso queira ver o código aqui está "<div id="exit_edit" ></div>"

Comment: @Zoom desculpe é minha primeira vez postando aqui e eu devia ter detalhado mais, mas sobre sua dúvida a input está com "display:none" e fica visível quando é clicado a div ".adm_edit"

Comment: @joaoPaulo desculpe minha primeira vez postando, mas obrigado por tentar ajudar hehe :). Na próxima vez vou tentar esclarecer melhor.

Answer (score 0):

Igor, tente armazenar o `.adm_edit` e o `.input_edit` atuais em alguma variavel com escopo mais amplo.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  (function () {    
    var atual = {};
    var inputs = {};

    inputs.exitEdit = $("#exit_edit");
    inputs.admEdit = $(".adm_edit");    
    inputs.admEdit.on("click", function() {
      atual.admEdit = $(this);
      atual.inputEdit = atual.admEdit.children(".input_edit");

      atual.inputEdit.show();
      inputs.exitEdit.show();
    });

    inputs.exitEdit.click(function() {
      atual.admEdit.text(atual.inputEdit.val());
      atual.inputEdit.hide();
      inputs.exitEdit.hide();
    });
  })():
});
```

Note que estou armazenando a `div.adm_edit` cliacado e o seu respesctivo `input.adm_edit` em uma variavel... fiz isto dentro de um closure para evitar problemas de escopo futuros.

Comment: Muito obrigado funcionou do jeito que eu queria :) e vou começar tentar utilizar sobre o que você falou sobre armazenar variáveis